# objective-c/c++/java/bash how to remove lines that is only newline

Tags: text, newline, removeall

I have a large text file that looks like:

```
string1
string2

string3
string4
string5

string6
string7
string8
string9
```

I don't care which programming language I have to use to solve it, I just want to remove lines that is only newline from that text file. I hope you have suggestion...

EDIT:

I can use Objective-C, Java, Bash, and a little C++.

The problem is if I remove all newlines or use it as a delimiter, the whole text will be compressed into one line...

Comment: You should **(1)** pick a language (otherwise the question is "too broad" - it has too many possible answers) and **(2)** try to solve the problem yourself first (otherwise the question classifies as off-topic since it does not "demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -v '^$' oldfile > newfile
```

`^$` is a regular expression that matches an empty line. `^` matches the beginning of the line, `$` matches the end of the line, and there's nothing between them. The `-v` option to `grep` means to print all lines that don't match the regular expression.

To learn about regular expressions, go to [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info)

Comment: Thanks! What does the symbol ^$ mean?

Comment: Added details to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I know about regular expression, but this was my biggest miss. Must give more attention when I read, hehe...